# Filter media of followers list using private Instagram API in PHP

Tags: php, instagram, instagramapi-mgp25

I'm using the [Instagram private API](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API) to get the followers list of any user, and I want to filter users who have 10 or more media.

The result is an array of users with 10 or more media. However, I received a response

> InstagramAPI\Response\FriendshipsShowManyResponse: Invalid user list.

I think my problem is in the following snippet. How can I fix this?

```
  $user_ids = [];
  foreach ($users as $i => $user) {
      if($user->getMediaCount()>10) {
           $user_ids[] = $user->getPk();
      }
  }
```

Comment: I would bet Instagram frequently breaks this usage, as it violates the TOS and they want you to stop doing it, especially after Facebook's Cambridge Analytica issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is deprecated by Instagram. See: https://www.instagram.com/developer/